# Why this error coming while running Node.js server?

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error while running Node.js Server:

```
Error: Not Found
    at C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var app = express();
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });
    // error handlers
    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }
    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });
    module.exports = app;
```

Comment: may be the app.js is not found in the "C:\wamp\www\scope-leads-node-master\MyApp\" path.Check whether it is present there or not

Comment: Thanks Subham , app.js is there. But i does not working.

Comment: Can you please share your app.js ? There seem to be some issue in that.

Comment: @robertklep - done! Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: How to share my code here? no idea about it

Comment: I have shared my app.js code. Please review this

Comment: Which one is line 30? Maybe it does not find your error template while it tries to render it. Or maybe it's just the development error, which is being logged.

Comment: I am new to nodejs, Thats y  I can't findout this. Its an already developed app

Comment: Is there any error.jade file available inside 'views' folder???

Comment: Yes 3 jade file are there inside views Subham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, It's working. I am still seeing that `not found` error in `http://localhost:3000`. But everything is working fine.  I have used another computer to do this.  Just did the following.

```
npm install express

npm install

npm start
```

NodeJS, git server should have been installed in our machine.

Answer (score 5):

Well it's an error you pass in the middleware you wrote (line 30):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

this code just passes an error on every HTTP request, you should comment it out.

Comment: I made that, But now getting this -->  Cannot GET /

Comment: actualy, I see you did add  app.use('/', routes);
but what is in th file './routes/index' ?

Comment: well there is no route defined for / in that file.
you should add a route or check one of the existing ons

Comment: Okay. i just start app using the following 

npm install express  -> npm start . 

is this okay, or am I done anything wrong?

Comment: You should start it with node app.js (or the main js file name)

Comment: But same error 404., This app is being used by my co developers , Its not working for me only.

Comment: I'm afraid I'd didn't understand

Comment: I have a related question.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625483/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-with-angular2-and-express-js

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error and found this thread while searching for an answer.

Here I'm sharing the way that you should tackle this error.

1. First, comment out the lines which handle your 404 error.

> ```
>  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
>     var err = new Error('Not Found');
>     err.status = 404;
>     next(err);  });
> ```

2. Now reload your page and you will see something like

> Cannot GET /(some route)

3. Understanding: The 404 or Not Found error message is the standard HTTP response code, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. And it now says the missing resource is on the route "/(some route)".
4. Handling the error

If it's a web page, the problem is "/(some route)" cannot be found in the JS files in `~/routes/` directory. You may have forgotten to handle that route or can be a typo or something. Handle it appropriately.

If it's a resource, make sure the resource exists in the mentioned route of your project.